# how to stop queueable job in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am working on queueable job in laravel its work fine and send the email using job prefectly but 
i given five record to send email so, email send to this five email id and after not stop but more and more time send the email

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Jobs\Admin;

 use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
 use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
 use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Mail;

 class TempleteEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
 {
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

protected $emailinfo_data;
/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($emailinfo_data)
{
    $this->emailinfo_data=$emailinfo_data;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(Request $request)
{
    $mail_data = $this->emailinfo_data;

    foreach ($mail_data as $key => $value)
    {
        $emails = [$value['email']];

        Mail::send('admin.templete.email', ['title' => $value], function($message) use ($emails)
        {    
            $message->to($emails)->subject('2');    
        });
    }
    return;
    }
}
```

mail_data have some data of send email like user email id.

[image]

like that loop is not stop and continue send mail to given email id

thank you.

Comment: Clear your jobs table and then stop your executed command, and if your code has some error so queues are working infinite time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if your script has error in local the job will be repeated over and over so you have to stop the queue then enter the command:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

then check the log files and fix the bug and run the queue again.